# What are the differences between the words 送る, 出す, 届ける?

Tags: word-choice

Not sure if there is a difference in formality or in terms of what is being sent.

Also, how would I say escort? Such as "I'll escort you back home"? I'm thinking that it may be 家まで見送ります, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"送る"　is an act of getting something out normally with your willingness. ex) Sending a letter to someone else because you need to do it. This time, we are not talking about if the receiver wants to take it or not.

"出す" is an act of getting something out. This time, the action is focused on the object is recognized in public rather than the agent's intention.

ex). "洗濯物を出す" implies your laundry needs getting out to be washed probably in a washing machine.

"届ける" is an act of getting something out normally with the receiver's  expectation.

ex). "落とし物を届ける"; The cell phone was left in somewhere and you will bring it to the authority such as train officer, koban policemen, etc. for the owner. This time, the reciever is normally pleased with the act of an object getting out to the receiver.